# AES encode in Delphi XE4 decode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, delphi, aes, delphi-xe4

I would like to AES encode in Delphi XE4 and decode in JavaScript.

My Delphi code:
(I use DCPcrypt Cryptographic Component Library v2 Beta 3)

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cipher : TDCP_rijndael;
  key: Ansistring;
  data: Ansistring;
  iv: Ansistring; 
begin
  Key := SHA256('password');
  IV :=   'cd6f6eea9a2a59f2';
  Data := '12345678901234567890';

Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.Create(Self);
if Length(Key) <= 16 then
  Cipher.Init(Key[1], 128, @IV[1])
else
  if Length(Key) <= 24 then
    Cipher.Init(Key[1], 192, @IV[1])
  else
    Cipher.Init(Key[1], 256, @IV[1]);
Cipher.EncryptCBC(Data[1],Data[1],Length(Data));

memo1.Lines.Add('DATA_ENC:'+DATA);
memo1.Lines.Add('DATA_BASE64_ENC: '+Base64encode(DATA));
```

end;

My JavaScript code (I use CryptoJS):

```
encypted = 'Pz8/yw0/ck+4tTY/Pn8zPz/f9D8=';  //input base64 text from Delphi routine

var key = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("password"));
var iv  =     CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('cd6f6eea9a2a59f2');
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted,key,
  keySize: 256,
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
  });
console.log('DECRYPTED: '+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I do not get back the original text, please help me. What is the matter?

Comment: Can you decrypt result via DCP? Do you get original text?

Comment: Why are you using CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse ? Just use the raw string.

Comment: Have you tried encrypring and decryptin block of binary data instead of string? The reason why I'm asking this is becouse as far as I know strings are being stored a bit differently in Delphi and JavaScript. And since encryption algorithms are always working with binary data you would be getting different results if you would try to encrypt same text in Delphi and JavaScript since the binary data in which these strings are stored is not the same.

Comment: Have you read [all other questions on using DCPCrypt and Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[delphi]+DCPcrypt)? This is a common issue, often resulting from confusing raw and Base64 encoded data, confusing bit and byte sizes (me!), incorrect use (by omission, or because the libraries use different ones by default) of the initialization vector or the padding. I suggest you do that first, then update your question with what you have tried/verified and what remains unclear.

Comment: It looks like your crypto is going to be insecure. If security matters, hire an expert consultant to advise you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about Delphi, so I can't help you there, but I can say, that your Delphi code is wrong, because if you parse the Base64 ciphertext and encode it as Hex, you will see this:

```
3f3f3fcb0d3f724fb8b5363f3e7f333f3fdff43f
```

A ciphertext of a modern cipher is supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise, but this ciphertext looks rather regular (there are a lot of 0x3f bytes).

---

Your JavaScript code is rather all over the place. Almost every string that you use, has a wrong encoding.

```js
run.onclick = function(){
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(inVal.value);

  var key = CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("password"));
  var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('cd6f6eea9a2a59f2');
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
    ciphertext: encrypted
  }, key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
  });
  outHex.innerHTML = decrypted.toString();
  outUtf8.innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/pad-zeropadding-min.js"></script>

<div>Base64 input: <input id="inVal" value="Pz8/yw0/ck+4tTY/Pn8zPz/f9D8="></div>
<div>Decrypted Hex: <span id="outHex">-</span></div>
<div>Decrypted Utf8: <span id="outUtf8">-</span></div>
<div><button id="run">Decrypt</button></div>
```

When you have fixed your Delphi code, you can include the Base64 in the above runnable snippet and see that decrypts correctly.

---

#### Security considerations:

- You need to use a random IV, if you're sending multiple ciphertexts with the same key. If you send the same message again, an attacker can see that only by observing ciphertexts. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext and remove it before decryption.
- SHA-256 is not sufficient for key derivation from a low-entropy password. You should use an iterated key derivation function (KDF) such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)
- It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.